# Is it possible to dynamically insert rows in an existing DataTable (No DataSource used)?

Tags: asp.net

I have created a datatable with three fields namely TimeTask, TaskItem and Count (count of user)  eg; {"12:30AM-01:00AM" , T1 , 3}.

```
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Task Time", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Task", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

        dataTable.Rows.Add("12:00AM-12:15AM", "T1", 6);
        dataTable.Rows.Add("12:45AM-01:00AM", "T1", 5);                             dataTable.Rows.Add("01:00AM-01:15AM", "T1", 1);
        dataTable.Rows.Add("01:15AM-01:30AM", "T2", 4);
        dataTable.Rows.Add("01:30AM-01:45AM", "T2", 9);            
        GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();



  In this there is no task for the TimeTask "12:15AM-12:30AM" and "12:30AM-12:45AM" yet the TimeTask should be inserted as,
```

TimeTask            TaskItem           Count
  12:00AM-12:15AM            T1             6
  12:15AM-12:30AM            -              -
  12:30AM-12:45AM            -              -
  12:45AM-01:00AM            T1             5
  01:00AM-01:15AM            T1             1
  01:15AM-01:30AM            T2             4
  01:30AM-01:45AM            T2             9

How to chk for the missing rows? Is it possible to dynamically insert rows in an existing DataTable (No DataSource used) in this scenario.pls help.Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Task Time"] = ....;
dr["Task"] = ....;
dr["Count"] = ....;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Should do the trick.